# How can I get a field value of a node using PHP?

Tags: entities

I have created a field in a Basic Page with the label of User Name and the field name of `field_user_name`.

How can I get it's value using PHP?

Comment: Whats the value of `$nid` in that context?

Comment: I do want to if fix it should be get automatically because when ever any user will create a new node than it should get automatically

Comment: No Drupal won't automatically inject code for you - if you want to load a node, you need to provide the nid to `node_load()` in some way

Comment: You won't see data with `print()`. Use `print_r($field_value);`. Or better `debug($field_value);`, or `dpm($field_value);`

Comment: If you have another question, then you should post it as a question rather than edit an existing one.  It'll get no visibility and won't help other people :)

Answer (score 10):

The easiest non Entity API way of doing it is to use [field_get_items()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7):

```
// Assuming you have the node object and assuming it is a single value
// field or you just want the first value of a multi value field.
$username_value = '';
if ($items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_user_name')) {
  $username_value = $items[0]['value'];
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Not sure what you mean by global PHP, but here goes anyway.

I'd use the [`entity_metadata_wrapper`()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!includes!entity.wrapper.inc/class/EntityMetadataWrapper/7). For further reference, there's the handbook page [here](https://drupal.org/node/1021556), but you're looking at something like the following:

```
// Assuming the NID if your Basic Page node is 123
$node = node_load(123);
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);

$field_value = $wrapper->FIELD_NAME->value();
```

You'd need the [Entity API](https://drupal.org/project/entity) installed, but if you're running D7 then it's a pretty safe bet that *something* will have required it in the past as a dependency.

Comment: How can I get node id ?

Comment: @MohitGoyal It's the ID of the node you're interested in loading. How you get it depends completely on the context your code is in